# VBA code to disable cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code that will rename sheet based on the cell values in the drop down list. I have two drop down list "C21" and "G17" and button that will help me in renaming the sheet.

My concern is, I need to disable cells from  "H1" to "M40" so that user cannot input data until he renames the sheet. Basically if button is executed successfully cells should be active, if not  "NO". Can you please help me?

```
Sub RenameCurrentSheet()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim worksh As Integer
    Dim worksheetexists As Boolean
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    worksh = Application.Sheets.Count
    worksheetexists = False
    ThisWorkbook.Unprotect Password:="xyz"
    For x = 1 To worksh
    If Worksheets(x).Name = ActiveSheet.Range("C21").Value & "-" & ActiveSheet.Range("G17").Value Then
            worksheetexists = True
            MsgBox ("Sheet with the name " + Worksheets(x).Name + " Already Exists!!!")
    Exit For
    End If
    Next x
    If worksheetexists = False Then
    For x = 1 To worksh
        If ActiveSheet.Name = "MainSheet" Then
            MsgBox "You Cannot Change Name of This Sheet!!!"
        Else
            ActiveSheet.Name = Range("C21").Value & "-" & Range("G17").Value
            Exit For
        End If
    Next x
    End If

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
ThisWorkbook.Protect Password:="xyz"
End Sub
```

Please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code to test sheet names, you could disable the cells with the code:

```
Range("H1:M40").Locked = True
```

and then it would be equal to false when the name is no longer a duplicate.

*Note* This will only work if the sheet is protected.

*Edit:*

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)  
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub  
    Set myRng = Range("H1:M40")  
    For Each C In myRng
        If C.Address = Target.Address And ActiveSheet.Name = ActiveSheet.Range("C21").Value & "-" & ActiveSheet.Range("G17").Value Then
            ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:= "xyz"  
            Range("H1:M40").Locked = False  
            ActiveSheet.Protect Password:= "xyz"  
            Exit For  
        Else  
            ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:= "xyz"  
            Range("H1:M40").Locked = True
            ActiveSheet.Protect Password:= "xyz"  
        End If  
    Next C  
End Sub
```

Comment: I have included the above line on the MainSheet  and not on the button (code I provided above was given for button/module). Cells are now getting disabled when the sheet name dosent match the value of 2 cells. But the problem is when the sheet name matches, it will take 4-5 clicks on the cell to get it active and its annoying. Am I doing something wrong..

Comment: See my edited code above for a worksheet selection event that will help with when to lock/unlock those cells.